# fontawesome not loading on some ie

Tags: fonts

I'm creating a static page which uses the fontawesome icons. It works great on my machines (a mcabook pro retina and an old towhiba laptop). The icons are display nicely on every browser: chrome, ff, ie+. But if I try opening the site from the client's laptop (he gave me an ibm, with the same window version as mine), I don't see the icons. There are no crossdomain or any other error in the console. I copy/pasted the code from the fontawesome webiste. I don't know where to look at anymore..

In the head I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then I use it like:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right arrow-link">&nbsp;</i><span class="dir">Follow Us</span></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: same problem... ever found a solution?

Comment: Not really, I guess they had infrastructural blocks and we switched to normal png icons. Sorry I can't help you any further